# How to create JPEG image of 65k x 65k size and 24 bits color deph using .NET and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, jpeg

Problem:

there is no way to create large JPEG image using .NET Framework classes like Bitmap with the following image properties:

1. width: 65000
2. height: 65000
3. color depth: 24 bits
4. compression: JPEG

Example of problem code:

```
Bitmap final = new Bitmap(65000, 65000, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

Expected Result:

I would like to find idea for solution or any other codes that could create large with properties mentioned above.

Actual Result:

The example of problem code just throws out of memory exception

Comment: Take a step back and explain why you need to do this, in case this is a XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: GDI+ is limited to the maximum size of a memory mapped file, 2 gigabytes.  WIC can do better, System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace.

Comment: WIC can do better - what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

To create such an image you need to store it in your RAM. The size of your image is at least 65000*65000*24 bits ~ **12 gigabytes**! 
Are you sure, that your system has such RAM capacity?

In case you aren't afraid of that big image, I suggest you to create your image by small chunks and save them to ROM memory. But then you can't use .Net `Bitmap` class.

Comment: The .Net Bitmap class couldn't solve my issue, so there should be solution how to create this image without Bitmap class, using, let's say, stream classes for this.

Comment: @Nick it could be possible, but I'm not sure that you can find ready-made solution. Get ready to implement it by yourself

Comment: I would like to find idea for solution that it is actually possible or not